# wrong dismissal after presenting a UIViewController working as a detail view of a tableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview

[image: File Organization]

In my project the app launches in ViewController, which loads inside a table (Table class) by adding it as a subview (ViewController.h - [self.view addSubview: Table.tableView];)

Camera Class is the detailed view, so when you tap in a table row it loads Camara.xib. Until here everything works fine.

The problem comes when I try to dismiss Camera.xib and go back to ViewController.xib, when I do that Camera.xib dismisses okay but instead of going back to ViewController.xib with Table.xib inside of it, the app only loads Table.xib, so the rest of objects that were placed in the view of ViewController.xib are not displaying.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!!

CODE:

Table.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    roomsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:nil];
    [super viewDidLoad];

}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // my code...

    Camara *camara = [[Camara alloc] initWithNibName:@"Camara" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:camara animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Camara.m

```
-(IBAction)cancel:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    table = [[Table alloc] initWithNibName:@"Table" bundle:nil];

    [windows.tableView reloadData];
    [self.view addSubview:windows.tableView];
    windows.tableView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 44);

    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
```

}

Comment: Why do you have seperate xibs for view and table? Why don't you combine them into one single view?

Comment: @CaptJak I would do it but it is too much work to do hahaha, however if you think that it is the problem I will combine them

Comment: Good things in life don't come from being lazy ;) I am not saying that it is the solution to the **exact** problem you are looking to solve (meaning solving the problem but keeping both nibs). But it is better practice to combine them, and I am pretty sure that it will solve the issue you are having as well.

Comment: Why did you post a duplicate of your previous question?

Comment: @rmaddy because the other one was not correctly answered and was not getting more views, so in order to make my question more visible again I reposted it. Thanks to doing this I got the answer. Sorry for reposting, I know it is not the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are having this problem is because the table view gets added on top of the first view, and they are separate VCs.

Picture the View Controllers as trays on a stack. You add and remove trays as you progress an navigate through the app.

I wouldn't suggest having separate View Controllers for the First VC and the tableview, but instead add the tableview into the first VC. The way you are building the stack makes it look like you want to always display the tableView and first VC together, which will not happen if they are separate ViewControllers.

It might take more code, but add the tableView to the first VC. That way, no matter what happens, they will always be shown together. Otherwise, your app won't work the way that you want it to.

Combine them, and your problem will be solved.

Comment: can't believe it solved the problem, I'll try to be less lazy hahahaha :P million thx!!